# Mac OS X - Printing too pale with laser printer

Tags: macos, laser-printer

I just bough a brand new MacBook but I have a problem with my printer. The model is a Samsung SCX-4200 B&W laser printer. Actually, it works fine with text but as soon as there is some "greyscale", it become unreadable. So I wonder if there is a way to adjust contrast or something like that? I know there's "Color Profile" in ICC format but I don't know if that can be useful...

I must say that everything works fine when I'm under Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a ML-2010 that defaults to "toner save" mode and the Mac drivers don't have an option to override the setting like the windows drivers do. :-(  The solution is to hold down the [Cancel] button until the toner save light goes out.

Comment: Are you talking of a "Cancel" buttons or a printer or in a Menu? 'Cause I don't have a button like this one on my printer :(

Comment: On the printer.. that's why I gave my model number.. I'm not sure if your printer will have the same feature/issue.

Comment: you may have luck looking for a "toner save" option in the print driver GUI.